# Where is the wrong in this roxygen in R documentation

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I am using roxygen to generate R documentation, everything is working great except when adding this example

```
@example dIconTr(c(c(1:2), NA)) and the answe is TRUE, dIconTr(c(1:2)) and the answer is FALSE
```

and the error message is:

```
cannot open file '/Users/myname/Documents/work/Development_Package/mypackage/dIconTr(c(c(1:2), NA)) and the answe is TRUE, dIconTr(c(1:2)) and the answer is FALSE': No such file or directory
Execution halted

Exited with status 1
```

when I remove that entry, `the example` entry, everything works find, I can build the package and commit it to git repository and publish it

Can you help in this point please?

Update 1:
After the first answer, I changed my example to :

```
#' @example doesItContainNullValues(c(1:2))
#' doesItContainNullValues(c(c(1:3), NA))
```

I didn't get error in R studio, but when I submit to git reposotry, all the documentation of all the function get corrupted, now I get this error

```
Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/mypackage/help/mypackage.rdb' is corrupt
```

Comment: Missing s: @example**s**

Comment: @bergant R studio tells me that there are two options, either `@example` or `@examples`. Anyway, I will try it and update you in 2 minutes

Comment: @bergant the problem kept the same

Comment: `@example` is for providing a path to an example script in your package, `@examples` is for giving **valid** r code examples. [read this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html)

Answer (score 0):

After @example or @examples you have to put executable R code.

Try

```
#' @example dIconTr(c(c(1:2), NA)) # and the answer is TRUE 
#' dIconTr(c(1:2)) #and the answer is FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for this new information. Also please what is the difference between example and exmaples? and in my case shouldn't I have used exmaples instead of example? because I wanna provide two examples

Comment: I don't know the exact difference, but I always used @example and put two ore more examples :)

Comment: I get a new error, and all the documentation of all the functions get corrupted , I updated the question with the new information ,could you check please?

Comment: and I just noticed that I kept having the same error that I had when I was using a wrong syntaxed example, so the building is not working still. I tried to use just one example and nothing changed, the same error and the same build error